# R or Stata shortcut to significance test interaction term including restricted cubic splines?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, interaction, likelihood-ratio, splines

I fit the following model in R using the lme4 package, which is a linear mixed effects regression of outcome "WT_abs_change" (absolute weight change) on various factors, including "ns(WT_dtime, df=3)*regimen" (interaction between time, using a natural/restricted cubic spline, and drug regimen, which is categorical with 5 categories):

fm1_adj<-lmer(WT_abs_change ~ ns(WT_dtime, df=3)*regimen + WT_baseline + ns(age_med, df=3) + female + black + MSM + ns(reg1yr, df=3) + ns(CD4_baseline, df=3) + (1|CFAR_PID), data=WT_naive_dataset)
summary(fm1_adj)

The model output follows:

> summary(fm1_adj)
>   Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
>   Formula: WT_abs_change ~ ns(WT_dtime, df = 3) * regimen + WT_baseline +
>       ns(age_med, df = 3) + female + black + MSM + ns(reg1yr, df = 3) +
>       ns(CD4_baseline, df = 3) + (1 | CFAR_PID)
>      Data: WT_naive_dataset

REML criterion at convergence: 71605.9

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-16.6026  -0.4862   0.0077   0.4769   5.8467

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 CFAR_PID (Intercept) 79.84    8.935
 Residual             81.74    9.041
Number of obs: 9559, groups:  CFAR_PID, 1174

Fixed effects:
                                     Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                         10.659383   2.781723   3.832
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)1               15.618293   1.440984  10.839
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)2               17.506589   1.685360  10.387
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)3               13.294438   1.126701  11.799
regimenEVG                           0.358854   1.562922   0.230
regimenNNRTI                        -0.876973   1.830318  -0.479
regimenPI                           -1.064086   1.755134  -0.606
regimenRAL                          -0.985957   2.187114  -0.451
WT_baseline                         -0.009162   0.006922  -1.324
ns(age_med, df = 3)1                 1.991276   1.361413   1.463
ns(age_med, df = 3)2                 0.297468   3.127315   0.095
ns(age_med, df = 3)3                 1.097583   2.426688   0.452
female                              -0.087786   0.983952  -0.089
black                                0.341828   0.605586   0.564
MSM                                  0.559518   0.789013   0.709
ns(reg1yr, df = 3)1                  2.067972   1.320659   1.566
ns(reg1yr, df = 3)2                 -3.173422   2.460025  -1.290
ns(reg1yr, df = 3)3                  1.123731   1.874192   0.600
ns(CD4_baseline, df = 3)1           -8.578638   1.964845  -4.366
ns(CD4_baseline, df = 3)2          -20.852911   3.082316  -6.765
ns(CD4_baseline, df = 3)3           -7.753365   4.906481  -1.580
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)1:regimenEVG    -9.270812   1.965526  -4.717
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)2:regimenEVG   -14.157056   2.306043  -6.139
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)3:regimenEVG   -11.326906   1.528430  -7.411
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)1:regimenNNRTI  -7.658012   1.697332  -4.512
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)2:regimenNNRTI  -7.420794   1.973527  -3.760
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)3:regimenNNRTI  -6.678979   1.317237  -5.070
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)1:regimenPI     -5.167451   1.622453  -3.185
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)2:regimenPI     -0.628741   1.899374  -0.331
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)3:regimenPI     -5.158171   1.258856  -4.098
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)1:regimenRAL    -5.068909   2.344669  -2.162
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)2:regimenRAL    -0.727831   2.863420  -0.254
ns(WT_dtime, df = 3)3:regimenRAL    -7.413167   1.832161  -4.046

I can then also use "visreg" to get lovely plots of outcome over time, by category of "regimen" (using the interaction including splines):

visreg(fm1_adj, "WT_dtime", by="regimen", overlay=TRUE, band=TRUE, partial=FALSE,  ylab="Weight (lbs.)", xlab="Months after ART-Start", ylim=c(150,190))

My question is: is there a shortcut or simple way to do a postestimation test (either LRT or Wald test) for differences between categories of my category-by-spline interaction, incorporating the spline terms appropriately (ideally using the model output, but potentially using the visreg predicted results)? Any advice would be appreciated; thank you!